# Grails - Return selected json elements from request parameter

Tags: json, grails

In my project, I am trying to return selected elements as JSON from requested parameter.

Domain Class:

```
class Component{
    String name
    String level
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I have http request like

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/component/showJson?name=name
```

so I should return only

```
{
   name:xyz
}
```

If my request is like

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/component/showJson?name=name&level=level
```

Then I should return

```
{
     name:xyz
     level:1
}
```

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Updated JSON (Multilevel)

```
[
   {"name":"one","level":0," 
         componentTypes":[
                {"name":"one one","level":1,
                    "componentTypes":[
                      {"name":"one one one","level":2,"componentTypes":[]}
                    ]
                 },
                 {"name":"one two","level":1,"componentTypes":[]}
         ]
   }, 
   {"name":"two","level":0,"componentTypes"[]},
   {"name":"three","level":0,"componentTypes":[]}
]

class ComponentType {
    String name
    Integer level
    static hasMany = [componentTypes:ComponentType]
    ComponentType parent
    static constraints = {
        parent nullable:true
    }
    static mapWith = "mongo"
}
```

Controller action

```
componentTypeList = ComponentType.createCriteria().list(){
            eq("level", 0)
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can intersect the params map with object properties map and return the result. I haven't tried this, but i can't think of a reason why it will not work.

```
def properties = component.properties;
def result = properties.subMap(params.keySet())
render result as JSON
```

**Update:**

```
class ComponentType {

    .
    .
    .



    def toJSON(def params) {
        def properties = this.properties
        def result = properties.subMap(params.keySet())
        if(this.componentTypes) {
            result.componentTypes = componentTypes*.toJSON(params)
        }
        result
    }
}


def componentTypeList = ComponentType.createCriteria().list(){ eq("level", 0) } 
render componentTypeList*.toJSON(params) as JSON
```

Comment: If we have components (list of items), then how to proceed

Comment: Updated answer for list of items.

Comment: The problem i face is, multilevel, component hasMany components

Comment: Can you Explain Lil More !

Comment: Please see the updated question, my json would look like

Comment: All the sub objects are going to be of same type ?

Comment: class ComponentType {
    String name
    Integer level
    static hasMany = [componentTypes:ComponentType]
    ComponentType parent
    static constraints = {
        parent nullable:true
    }
    static mapWith = "mongo"
}

Comment: componentTypeList = ComponentType.createCriteria().list(){
            eq("level", 0)
        }

Comment: Updated my Answer, Try it out.

Comment: Getting exception No signature of method: com.causecode.storelocator.ComponentType.toJSON() is applicable for argument types: (grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap) values: [[name:name, action:complete, format:null, controller:componentType]]

Comment: Are you sure that the domain is compiled ?

Comment: Yes. I have checked it. Still getting the same exception